# A noun to describe character sequences between words

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm creating a formal system in which a sentence can be formed by four types of sequences of characters:

1. Words
2. Prefixes
3. Suffixes
4. Sequences in between words

What noun would you use to describe a sequence of characters between words?

I initially thought of "spaces" but that didn't seem appropriate as you could form sentences like *cat->scratch*, and *->* is definitely not a space.

A friend of mine suggested "delimiters" but here *->* doesn't delimit anything. Now we're both out of nouns.

Comment: They are not necessarily spaces or delimiters. They are **non-lexical entities** in language. In a programming context, they do have meaning and function in a way similar to words/ phrases. You need to call them either *symbols* or consider the first three of the above group as *lexicals* and the last as *non-lexicals* (note that *lexical* is an adjective *per se*.)

Comment: @Kris - Calling them __non-lexical entities__ sounds too vague. I'm looking for a single-word adjective to describe it.

Comment: Your problem is that you're hoping that the natural language English contains words in its lexis that are sufficient to cater for every possible feature of a formal language. English isn't like that; you may or may not be able to find single-word terms that are close enough in meaning to be readily transferable to the formal language. Linguists even have problems with meta-language (the language used to describe how 'natural English' works): is 'particle board' a word?

Comment: Do you want an adjective or a noun? "Words", "prefixes", and "suffixes" are nouns. Are you looking for a corresponding noun? If so, you should change the subject of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `junction` and state somewhere that junctions may include any number of spaces, but a valid junction can not contain zero spaces alone.

Use `conjunction` and say they may also be used to separate words.

e.g

`4`. Junction (separates or joins words with " ", "->", ":" - space, arrow and colon)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you're looking for a *noun*, since you're *naming* things.

Since you're looking for something other than [*white space*](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=white%20space), I would suggest *[glyph](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=glyph)*, especially in this sense:

> A symbol, such as a stylized figure or arrow on a public sign, that
>   imparts information nonverbally.

Or, simply go with *symbol*.